# My java program is giving me 99 wrong errors

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am fairly new to programming.I am currently studying java in my first year of college.I was given a group java project.My part of the project is giving me 96 different errors but none of the errors given actually are wrong.The project takes in between 1 and 7 command line arguments. It then does different things depending on what was entered.It overall analyses different parts of a file that represents the Lotto.I compile my program with the command line.I can post all of the errors if it is requested.First off here is my entire code but I had to take out a method so that it would fit in one post.The method I took out is error free as I have that checked already.It was the arguments method.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Text1
{
  public static final String filename = "SampleLottoData.txt";
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, ParseException, AssertionError 
  {
  File Numbers = new File(filename);
  Scanner in = new Scanner(Numbers);
  if(Numers.exists())
   {
   ArgumentCheck(args);
   if(args.length <= 5)
    int choice = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   if (args.length >= 2 && args.length <= 5)
    String drawtype = args[1].toUpperCase();
   if(args.length >= 3 %% args.length <= 5)
    int day = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
   if(args.length == 4)
    int year = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
   if(args.length == 1)
    JackpotOrBonus(args,in,choice);
     else if(args.length == 2)
      TypeOfDraw(args,in,choice,drawtype);
       else if(args.length == 3)
        DrawOnADay(args,in,choice,drawtype,day);
         else if(args.length == 4)
          DrawForAYear(args,in,choice,drawtype,day,year);
           else if(args.length == 5)
            BetweenTwoDates(args,in,choice,drawtype,day);
   }
  else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The file " + filename + " doesn't exist");
}

  public static void JackpotOrBonus(String [] args,Scanner in,int choice) throws IOException
   {
    int [] jackpotnumbers = new int[45], int [] bonusnumbers = new int[45], int [] jackpot = new int[6], int bonus = 0;
    String data = "";
    String [] temp = new String[9];
     if(choice == 1)
      {
       while(in.hasNext())
       {
       data = in.nextLine();
       temp = data.split(",");
        for(int counter = 0;counter < jackpot.length;counter++)
        {
         jackpot[counter] = Integer.parseInt(temp[counter + 1]);
         jackpotnumbers[jackpot[counter] - 1]++;
         }
         }
         in.close();
         }
      else
       {
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
         data = in.nextLine();
         temp = data.split(",");  
         bonus = Integer.parseInt(temp[7]);
         bonusnumbers[bonus - 1]++;
        }
        in.close();
       }
    Printing(args,jackpotnumbers,bonusnumbers);    
   }


  public static void TypeOfDraw(String [] args,Scanner in,int choice,String drawtype) throws IOException
  { 
   int [] jackpotnumbers = new int[45], int [] bonusnumbers = new int[45], int [] jackpot = new int[6], int bonus = 0;
   String data = "";
   String [] temp = new String[9];
   if(choice == 1 || choice == 2)
    {
     while(in.hasNext())
     {
     data = in.nextLine();
     temp = data.split(",");
      if(temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype) || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
       for(int count = 0;count<jackpot.length;count++)
       {
       jackpot[count] = Integer.parseInt(temp[count + 1]);
       jackpotnumbers[jackpot[count] - 1]++;  
       }
     }
     in.close();
    }
     if(choice == 2)
      {
      while(in.hasNext())
       {
       data = in.nextLine();
       temp = data.split(",");
       bonus = Integer.parseInt(temp[7]);
        if(temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype) || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
         bonusnumbers[bonus - 1]++;  
       }
       in.close();
      }
     Printing(args,jackpotnumbers,bonusnumbers); 
  }


  public static void DrawOnADay(String [] args,Scanner in,int choice,String drawtype,int day) throws IOException
  {  
    int [] jackpotnumbers = new int[45], int [] bonusnumbers = new int[45], int [] jackpot = new int[6], int bonus = 0;
    String data = "",weekday;
    String [] temp = new String[9];
     if(choice == 1 || choice == 2)
      {
      while(in.hasNext())
       {
       data = in.nextLine();
       temp = data.split(",");
       weekday = convertDateToWeekDay(temp);
       if(weekday == day || day == 0);
        {
        if(temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype) || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
         for(int count = 0;count<jackpot.length;count++)
         {
         jackpot[count] = Integer.parseInt(temp[count + 1]);
         jackpotnumbers[jackpot[count] - 1]++;  
         }
        }
        in.close;();
       }
       if(choice == 2)
        {
        while(in.hasNext())
         {
         data = in.nextLine();
         temp = data.split(",");
         weekday = convertDateToWeekDay(temp);
         if(weekday == day || day == 0);
          {
          bonus = Integer.parseInt(temp[7]);
          if(temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype) || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
           bonusnumbers[bonus - 1]++;      
         }
       }
       in.close();
       }
     }
     Printing(args,jackpotnumbers,bonusnumbers); 
   }      

  public static void DrawsForAYear(String [] args,Scanner in,int choice,String drawtype,int day,int year) throws IOException
   {
    int [] jackpotnumbers = new int[45], int [] bonusnumbers = new int[45], int [] jackpot = new int[6], int bonus = 0;
    String data = "",weekday;
    String [] temp = new String[9];   
    String temporary = temp[0];
    String [] temps = temporary.split("/");
    int years = Integer.parseInt(temps[2]);
    weekday = convertDateToWeekDay(temp);
     while(in.hasNext())
      {
      data = in.nextLine();
      temp = data.split(",");
      String temporary = temp[0];
      String [] temps = temporary.split("/");
      int years = Integer.parseInt(temps[2]);
      weekday = convertDateToWeekDay(temp);
       if((year == years) && (temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype) || drawtype.contentEquals("A")) && (weekday == day || day == 0))
       {
        if (choice == 1 || choice == 2)
         {
         for(int count = 0;count<jackpot.length;count++)
         {
         jackpot[count] = Integer.parseInt(temp[count + 1]);
         jackpotnumbers[jackpot[count] - 1]++; 
         }
        }
        if(choice == 2)
         {
         bonus = Integer.parseInt(temp[7]);
         if(temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype) || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
         bonusnumbers[bonus - 1]++;    
         }
       }
      }
      in.close();
      EvenOrOdd(args,choice,in);
      Printing(args,jackpotnumbers,bonusnumbers,year); 
   }


  public static void EvenOrOdd(String [] args,int choice,Scanner in,int year)
  { 
   int length, number,odd = 0,even = 0,lowexceedshighr,lowexceedshighs,lowexceedshighlp1,lowexceedshighlp2;
   String data = "",weekday;
   String [] temp = new String[9];   
   if(choice == 1)
    length = 6;
     else 
      length = 7;
   while(in.hasNext())
    {
    int oddcounter = 0, evencounter = 0;
    data = in.nextLine();
    temp = data.split(",");   
    String temporary = temp[0];
    String [] temps = temporary.split("/");
    for(int counter = 0;counter<length;counter++)
    {
    number = Integer.parseInt(temp[counter + 1]);
     if(number % 2 == 0)
      evencounter++;
       else 
       oddcounter++;
    }
    if(evencounter == length)
     even++;
      else if(oddcounter == length)
       odd++;
   int years = Integer.parseInt(temps[2]);
   if (year == years)
    {
    int high = 36;
    String 39s = "22/08/1992", 42s = "24/09/1994", 45s = "4/11/2006";
    String datayear = temp[0];
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date datas = df.parse(datayear);
    Date 39ss = df.parse(39s);
    Date 42ss = df.parse(42s);
    Date 45ss = df.parse(45s);
    if(datas.equals(39ss) || (datas.after(39ss) && datas.before(42ss)))
     high = 39;
      else if(datas.equals(42ss) || (datas.after(42ss) && datas.before(45ss)))
       high  42;
        else if(datas.equals(45ss) || (datas.after(45ss)))
         high = 45;
    int limit = (high - 10);
    for(int count = 0;count<jackpot.length;count++)
    jackpot[count] = Integer.parseInt(temp[count + 1]);
    int lowwinning = 0,highwinning = 0,
    for(int counter = 0;counter<jackpot.length;counter++)
    {
     if(jackpot[counter] <= 10)
      lowwinning++;
       else if(jackpot[counter] >= limit)
        highwinning++;   
    }
    if (lowwining > highwinning)
    {
     if(temp[8].contentEquals("R"))
      lowexceedshighr++;
       else if(temp[8].contentEquals("S"))
        lowexceedshighs++;
         else if(temp[8].contentEquals("LP1"))
          lowexceedshighlp1++;
           else if(temp[8].contentEquals("LP2"))
            lowexceedshighlp2++;
    }
   }
   in.close();
   String results = "";
   if(choice == 1)
   {
    results = "All Jackpot numbers were even " + even + " times.\n";
    results += "All Jackpot numbers were odd " + odd + " times.\n";   
   }
  else
  {
   results = "All Jackpot and Bonus numbers were even " + even + " times.\n";
   results += "All Jackpot and Bonus numbers were odd " + odd + " times.\n";      
  }
  results += "In " + args[3] + " low winning numbers exceeded high winning numbers\n";
  results += lowexceedshighr + " in regular draws.\n";
  results += lowexceedshighs + " in special draws.\n";
  results += lowexceedshighlp1 + " in Lotto Plus 1 draws.\n";
  results += lowexceedshighlp2 + " in Lotto Plus 2 draws.";
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,results,"Analysing the Lotto",1);  
}


  public static void BetweenTwoDates(String [] args,Scanner in,int choice,String drawtype,int day) throws IOException, ParseException, AssertionError
  {
   int [] jackpotnumbers = new int[45], int [] bonusnumbers = new int[45], int [] jackpot = new int[6], int bonus = 0;
   String data = "",weekday;
   String [] temp = new String[9];
    while(in.hasNext())
    {
     data = in.nextLine();
     temp = data.split(",");
     String firstyear = args[3];
     String secondyear = args[4];
     String datayear = temp[0];
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     Date first = df.parse(firstyear);
     Date second = df.parse(secondyear);
     Date datas = df.parse(datayear);
     weekday = convertDateToWeekDay(temp);
     if(weekday == day || day == 0);
     {
      if(temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype) || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
      {
       if((datas.equals(first)) || (datas.equals(second)) || ((datas.after(first)) && (datas.before(second))))
       {
        if(choice == 1 || choice == 2)
         {
         for(int count = 0;count<jackpot.length;count++)
         {
         jackpot[count] = Integer.parseInt(temp[count + 1]);
         jackpotnumbers[jackpot[count] - 1]++;  
         }
         }
       if(choice == 2)
        {
        bonus = Integer.parseInt(temp[7]);
        if(temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype) || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
         bonusnumbers[bonus - 1]++;    
        }
      }       
    }
   }
   }
   in.close();
   Printing(args,jackpotnumbers,bonusnumbers); 
  } 



  public static int convertDateToWeekDay(String [] temp)
  {
    int result = 0; 
    int a, b, d, m, y, dayOfWeek;
    String date = temp[0];
    String [] dates = date.split("/");
    d = Integer.parseInt(dates[0]); 
    m = Integer.parseInt(dates[1]);
    y = Integer.parseInt(dates[2]);
    if (m == 1 || m == 2)
    {
      m += 12; y -=  1;
    }
    a = y % 100;  b = y / 100;
    dayOfWeek = ((d + (((m + 1)*26)/10)+ a + (a/4) + (b/4)) + (5*b)) % 7;
    switch(dayOfWeek)
    {
      case 0: result = 2;  break;
      case 4: result = 1; break;
    } 
    return result;
  } 


  public static void Printing(String [] args,int [] jackpotnumbers,int [] bonusnumbers)
  {
  String results = "";
  if(args.length == 1)
  {
  if(choice == 1)
        {
        results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for the entire file.\n\n";
        for(int counter = 0;counter<45;counter++)
        {
        int num = counter + 1;
        results+= num + " was a jackpot number " + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
        }
        }
       else
        {
        results = "An Analsis of Bonus Numbers for the entire file.\n\n";
        for(int counter = 0;counter<45;counter++)
        {
        int num = counter + 1;
        results+= num + " was a bonus number " + bonusnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
        }   
        }
   }
   if(args.length == 2)
   {
    if(choice == 1)
        {
        if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
         results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for the entire file.\n\n";
          else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
           results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all regular draws.\n\n";
            else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
             results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all special draws.\n\n";
              else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
               results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws.\n\n";
                else
                 results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws.\n\n";
        for(int counter = 0;counter<45;counter++)
        {
        int num = counter + 1;
        results+= num + " was a jackpot number " + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
        }
        }
       else
        {
        if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
         results = "An Analsis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for the entire file.\n\n";
          else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
           results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all regular draws.\n\n";
            else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
             results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all special draws.\n\n";
              else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
               results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws.\n\n";
                else
                 results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws.\n\n";
        for(int counter = 0;counter<45;counter++)
        {
        int num = counter + 1;
        results+= num + " was a bonus number " + bonusnumbers[counter] + "times and a jackpot number " + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
        } 
     if(args.length == 3)
         { 
         int numb = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); 
        if(choice == 1)
         {
         if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
          results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for the entire file";
           else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all regular draws";
             else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
              results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all special draws";
               else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                 else
                  results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";
        if(numb == 2)
         results += " on Wednesday draws.\n\n\";
          else if(numb == 1)
           results += " on Saturday draws.\n\n\";
            else
             results += " for all draws.\n\n\";
        for(int counter = 0;counter<45;counter++)
        {
        int num = counter + 1;
        results+= num + " was a jackpot number " + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
        }
        }
       else
        {
         if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
          results = "An Analsis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for the entire file";
           else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all regular draws";
             else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
              results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all special draws";
               else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                 else
                  results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";
        if(numb == 2)
         results += " on Wednesday draws.\n\n";
          else if(numb == 1)
           results += " on Saturday draws.\n\n";
            else
             results += " for all draws.\n\n";
        for(int counter = 0;counter<45;counter++)
        {
        int num = counter + 1;
        results+= num + " was a bonus number " + bonusnumbers[counter] + "times and a jackpot number " + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
        }   
        }
        }
         if(args.length == 5)
         { 
         int numb = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); 
        if(choice == 1)
         {
         if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
          results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for the entire file";
           else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all regular draws";
             else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
              results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all special draws";
               else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                 else
                  results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";
        if(numb == 2)
         results += " on Wednesday draws\n\n";
          else if(numb == 1)
           results += " on Saturday draws\n\n";
            else
             results += " for all draws\n\n";
          results += "for " + args[3] + ".\n\n";
        for(int counter = 0;counter<45;counter++)
        {
        int num = counter + 1;
        results+= num + " was a jackpot number " + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
        }
        }
       else
        {
         if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
          results = "An Analsis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for the entire file";
           else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all regular draws";
             else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
              results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all special draws";
               else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                 else
                  results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";        
        if(numb == 2)
         results += " on Wednesday draws";
          else if(numb == 1)
           results += " on Saturday draws";
            else
             results += " for all draws";
         results += "for " + args[3] + ".\n\n";
        for(int counter = 0;counter<45;counter++)
        {
        int num = counter + 1;
        results+= num + " was a bonus number " + bonusnumbers[counter] + "times and a jackpot number " + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
        }   
        }
        }
     if(args.length == 5)
         { 
         int numb = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); 
        if(choice == 1)
         {
         if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
          results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for the entire file";
           else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all regular draws";
             else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
              results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all special draws";
               else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                 else
                  results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";
        if(numb == 2)
         results += " on Wednesday draws\n\n";
          else if(numb == 1)
           results += " on Saturday draws\n\n";
            else
             results += " for all draws\n\n";
          results += "between " + args[3] + " and " + args[4] + ".\n\n";
        for(int counter = 0;counter<45;counter++)
        {
        int num = counter + 1;
        results+= num + " was a jackpot number " + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
        }
        }
       else
        {
         if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
          results = "An Analsis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for the entire file";
           else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all regular draws";
             else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
              results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all special draws";
               else if((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                 else
                  results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";        
        if(numb == 2)
         results += " on Wednesday draws";
          else if(numb == 1)
           results += " on Saturday draws";
            else
             results += " for all draws";
         results += "between " + args[3] + " and " + args[4] + ".\n\n";
        for(int counter = 0;counter<45;counter++)
        {
        int num = counter + 1;
        results+= num + " was a bonus number " + bonusnumbers[counter] + "times and a jackpot number " + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
        }   
        }
        }
    }   
   }
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,results,"Analysing the Lotto",1);   
  }
}
```

I am sorry for the long code but I have no idea where any problems actually are.I am also sorry its not commented, the final version will be.I am not able to post all of the errors here due to the character limit.How can I show ye what the errors are.There are 96 errors but none of them seem valid at all.The errors are different versions of the following:

```
Text1.java:541: error: unclosed string literal
             results += " for all draws.\n\n\";
Text1.java:391: error: <identifier> expected
   int [] jackpotnumbers = new int[45], int [] bonusnumbers = new int[45], int [
] jackpot = new int[6], int bonus = 0;
Text1.java:391: error: ';' expected
   int [] jackpotnumbers = new int[45], int [] bonusnumbers = new int[45], int [
] jackpot = new int[6], int bonus = 0;
Text1.java:391: error: illegal start of expression
   int [] jackpotnumbers = new int[45], int [] bonusnumbers = new int[45], int [
] jackpot = new int[6], int bonus = 0;
Text1.java:349: error: not a statement
    for(int counter = 0;counter<jackpot.length;counter++)
Text1.java:23: error: '.class' expected
    int year = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
```

If you need more information just ask.Any help would be hugely appreciated as I have no idea what to do now and I can't write all of that code again as the project is due on Tuesday.

Comment: remove the last back slash in `results += " for all draws.\n\n\";` It escapes the " with the result being the string is not closed

Comment: I did that and now I have 100 errors

Comment: Well you've got that problem 3 times, and then plenty of other problems - for example `String 39s = "22/08/1992", 42s = "24/09/1994", 45s = "4/11/2006";` You can't start a variable with a digit. And that's just picking *one* of the errors...

Comment: Basically, I would suggest you start again, and compile *often*. As soon as you've got an error, fix it. That way you won't end up with such a huge problem.

Comment: Better yet, use an IDE such as Eclipse so that you will know immediately when you have made an error.

Comment: Also when you have multiple variable declared in the same statement, you don't redeclare the type ( int [] a,b,c; instead of int[] a, int[] b, int[] c;) also make methods out of repeated code blocks instead of copying and  pasting.

Comment: You are combining declarations in a way that is not valid. You can combine them (without repeating the type) when they are the same type e.g., `int x = 0, y = 0;` but otherwise you should put them on separate lines, separated by semicolons.

Comment: I know there is huge overlap in parts of the code.That was the next thing I was going to fix but I wanted a working program first.I also did compile often,this problem came out of nowhere there were no errors a few minutes before this came up.I will change the variable starting with a digit

Comment: Changing the variable starting with a digit brought the errors down to 83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ye your code looked messed up looks like you did it on notepad and run it in cmd or something anyway i was able to remove the syntax errors. Hopefully the code will be readable to fellow stackoverflow users and help you with that 99 problems so you can move on to fixing the real thing.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Text1 {
    public static final String filename = "SampleLottoData.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException,
            AssertionError {
        File Numbers = new File(filename);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(Numbers);
        if (Numbers.exists()) {
            // ArgumentCheck(args);
            if (args.length <= 5) {
                int choice = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                if (args.length >= 2 && args.length <= 5) {
                    String drawtype = args[1].toUpperCase();

                    if (args.length >= 3 && args.length <= 5) {
                        int day = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

                        if (args.length == 4) {
                            int year = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

                            if (args.length == 1) {
                                JackpotOrBonus(args, in, choice);
                            } else if (args.length == 2) {
                                TypeOfDraw(args, in, choice, drawtype);
                            } else if (args.length == 3) {
                                DrawOnADay(args, in, choice, drawtype, day);
                            } else if (args.length == 4) {
                                DrawsForAYear(args, in, choice, drawtype, day,
                                        year);
                            } else if (args.length == 5) {
                                BetweenTwoDates(args, in, choice, drawtype, day);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file " + filename
                    + " doesn't exist");
    }

    public static void JackpotOrBonus(String[] args, Scanner in, int choice)
            throws IOException {
        int[] jackpotnumbers = new int[45];
        int[] bonusnumbers = new int[45];
        int[] jackpot = new int[6];
        int bonus = 0;
        String data = "";
        String[] temp = new String[9];
        if (choice == 1) {
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                data = in.nextLine();
                temp = data.split(",");
                for (int counter = 0; counter < jackpot.length; counter++) {
                    jackpot[counter] = Integer.parseInt(temp[counter + 1]);
                    jackpotnumbers[jackpot[counter] - 1]++;
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } else {
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                data = in.nextLine();
                temp = data.split(",");
                bonus = Integer.parseInt(temp[7]);
                bonusnumbers[bonus - 1]++;
            }
            in.close();
        }
        Printing(args, jackpotnumbers, bonusnumbers, bonus);
    }

    public static void TypeOfDraw(String[] args, Scanner in, int choice,
            String drawtype) throws IOException {
        int[] jackpotnumbers = new int[45];
        int[] bonusnumbers = new int[45];
        int[] jackpot = new int[6];
        int bonus = 0;
        String data = "";
        String[] temp = new String[9];
        if (choice == 1 || choice == 2) {
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                data = in.nextLine();
                temp = data.split(",");
                if (temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype)
                        || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
                    for (int count = 0; count < jackpot.length; count++) {
                        jackpot[count] = Integer.parseInt(temp[count + 1]);
                        jackpotnumbers[jackpot[count] - 1]++;
                    }
            }
            in.close();
        }
        if (choice == 2) {
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                data = in.nextLine();
                temp = data.split(",");
                bonus = Integer.parseInt(temp[7]);
                if (temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype)
                        || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
                    bonusnumbers[bonus - 1]++;
            }
            in.close();
        }
        Printing(args, jackpotnumbers, bonusnumbers, bonus);
    }

    public static void DrawOnADay(String[] args, Scanner in, int choice,
            String drawtype, int day) throws IOException {
        int[] jackpotnumbers = new int[45];
        int[] bonusnumbers = new int[45];
        int[] jackpot = new int[6];
        int bonus = 0;
        String data = "";
        int weekday;
        String[] temp = new String[9];
        if (choice == 1 || choice == 2) {
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                data = in.nextLine();
                temp = data.split(",");
                weekday = convertDateToWeekDay(temp);
                if (weekday == day || day == 0)
                    ;
                {
                    if (temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype)
                            || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
                        for (int count = 0; count < jackpot.length; count++) {
                            jackpot[count] = Integer.parseInt(temp[count + 1]);
                            jackpotnumbers[jackpot[count] - 1]++;
                        }
                }
                in.close();
            }
            if (choice == 2) {
                while (in.hasNext()) {
                    data = in.nextLine();
                    temp = data.split(",");
                    weekday = convertDateToWeekDay(temp);
                    if (weekday == day || day == 0)
                        ;
                    {
                        bonus = Integer.parseInt(temp[7]);
                        if (temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype)
                                || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
                            bonusnumbers[bonus - 1]++;
                    }
                }
                in.close();
            }
        }
        Printing(args, jackpotnumbers, bonusnumbers, bonus);
    }

    public static void DrawsForAYear(String[] args, Scanner in, int choice,
            String drawtype, int day, int year) throws IOException,
            ParseException {
        int[] jackpotnumbers = new int[45];
        int[] bonusnumbers = new int[45];
        int[] jackpot = new int[6];
        int bonus = 0;
        String data = "";
        int weekday;
        String[] temp = new String[9];
        String temporary = temp[0];
        String[] temps = temporary.split("/");
        int years = Integer.parseInt(temps[2]);
        weekday = convertDateToWeekDay(temp);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            data = in.nextLine();
            temp = data.split(",");
            temporary = temp[0];
            temps = temporary.split("/");
            years = Integer.parseInt(temps[2]);
            weekday = convertDateToWeekDay(temp);
            if ((year == years)
                    && (temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype) || drawtype
                            .contentEquals("A"))
                    && (weekday == day || day == 0)) {
                if (choice == 1 || choice == 2) {
                    for (int count = 0; count < jackpot.length; count++) {
                        jackpot[count] = Integer.parseInt(temp[count + 1]);
                        jackpotnumbers[jackpot[count] - 1]++;
                    }
                }
                if (choice == 2) {
                    bonus = Integer.parseInt(temp[7]);
                    if (temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype)
                            || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
                        bonusnumbers[bonus - 1]++;
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
        EvenOrOdd(args, choice, in, years);
        Printing(args, jackpotnumbers, bonusnumbers, year);
    }

    public static void EvenOrOdd(String[] args, int choice, Scanner in, int year)
            throws ParseException {
        int length, number, odd = 0, even = 0, lowexceedshighr = 0, lowexceedshighs = 0, lowexceedshighlp1 = 0, lowexceedshighlp2 = 0;
        String data = "", weekday;
        String[] temp = new String[9];
        int[] jackpot = new int[6];
        if (choice == 1)
            length = 6;
        else
            length = 7;
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            int oddcounter = 0, evencounter = 0;
            data = in.nextLine();
            temp = data.split(",");
            String temporary = temp[0];
            String[] temps = temporary.split("/");
            for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++) {
                number = Integer.parseInt(temp[counter + 1]);
                if (number % 2 == 0)
                    evencounter++;
                else
                    oddcounter++;
            }
            if (evencounter == length)
                even++;
            else if (oddcounter == length)
                odd++;
            int years = Integer.parseInt(temps[2]);
            if (year == years) {
                int high = 36;
                String s39 = "22/08/1992";
                String s42 = "24/09/1994";
                String s45 = "4/11/2006";
                String datayear = temp[0];
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date datas = df.parse(datayear);
                Date ss39 = df.parse(s39);
                Date ss42 = df.parse(s42);
                Date ss45 = df.parse(s45);
                if (datas.equals(ss39)
                        || (datas.after(ss39) && datas.before(ss42)))
                    high = 39;
                else if (datas.equals(ss42)
                        || (datas.after(ss42) && datas.before(ss45)))
                    high = 42;
                else if (datas.equals(ss45) || (datas.after(ss45)))
                    high = 45;
                int limit = (high - 10);
                for (int count = 0; count < jackpot.length; count++)
                    jackpot[count] = Integer.parseInt(temp[count + 1]);
                int lowwinning = 0, highwinning = 0;
                for (int counter = 0; counter < jackpot.length; counter++) {
                    if (jackpot[counter] <= 10)
                        lowwinning++;
                    else if (jackpot[counter] >= limit)
                        highwinning++;
                }
                if (lowwinning > highwinning) {
                    if (temp[8].contentEquals("R"))
                        lowexceedshighr++;
                    else if (temp[8].contentEquals("S"))
                        lowexceedshighs++;
                    else if (temp[8].contentEquals("LP1"))
                        lowexceedshighlp1++;
                    else if (temp[8].contentEquals("LP2"))
                        lowexceedshighlp2++;
                }
            }
            in.close();
            String results = "";
            if (choice == 1) {
                results = "All Jackpot numbers were even " + even + " times.\n";
                results += "All Jackpot numbers were odd " + odd + " times.\n";
            } else {
                results = "All Jackpot and Bonus numbers were even " + even
                        + " times.\n";
                results += "All Jackpot and Bonus numbers were odd " + odd
                        + " times.\n";
            }
            results += "In " + args[3]
                    + " low winning numbers exceeded high winning numbers\n";
            results += lowexceedshighr + " in regular draws.\n";
            results += lowexceedshighs + " in special draws.\n";
            results += lowexceedshighlp1 + " in Lotto Plus 1 draws.\n";
            results += lowexceedshighlp2 + "in Lotto Plus 2 draws.";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, results, "", 1);
        }

    }

    public static void BetweenTwoDates(String[] args, Scanner in, int choice,
            String drawtype, int day) throws IOException, ParseException,
            AssertionError {
        int[] jackpotnumbers = new int[45];
        int[] bonusnumbers = new int[45];
        int[] jackpot = new int[6];
        int bonus = 0;
        String data = "";
        int weekday = 0;
        String[] temp = new String[9];
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            data = in.nextLine();
            temp = data.split(",");
            String firstyear = args[3];
            String secondyear = args[4];
            String datayear = temp[0];
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date first = df.parse(firstyear);
            Date second = df.parse(secondyear);
            Date datas = df.parse(datayear);
            weekday = convertDateToWeekDay(temp);
            if (weekday == day || day == 0)
                ;
            {
                if (temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype)
                        || drawtype.contentEquals("A")) {
                    if ((datas.equals(first)) || (datas.equals(second))
                            || ((datas.after(first)) && (datas.before(second)))) {
                        if (choice == 1 || choice == 2) {
                            for (int count = 0; count < jackpot.length; count++) {
                                jackpot[count] = Integer
                                        .parseInt(temp[count + 1]);
                                jackpotnumbers[jackpot[count] - 1]++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (choice == 2) {
                            bonus = Integer.parseInt(temp[7]);
                            if (temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype)
                                    || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
                                bonusnumbers[bonus - 1]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
        Printing(args, jackpotnumbers, bonusnumbers, weekday);
    }

    public static int convertDateToWeekDay(String[] temp) {
        int result = 0;
        int a, b, d, m, y, dayOfWeek;
        String date = temp[0];
        String[] dates = date.split("/");
        d = Integer.parseInt(dates[0]);
        m = Integer.parseInt(dates[1]);
        y = Integer.parseInt(dates[2]);
        if (m == 1 || m == 2) {
            m += 12;
            y -= 1;
        }
        a = y % 100;
        b = y / 100;
        dayOfWeek = ((d + (((m + 1) * 26) / 10) + a + (a / 4) + (b / 4)) + (5 * b)) % 7;
        switch (dayOfWeek) {
        case 0:
            result = 2;
            break;
        case 4:
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void Printing(String[] args, int[] jackpotnumbers,
            int[] bonusnumbers, int choice) {
        String results = "";
        if (args.length == 1) {
            if (choice == 1) {
                results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for the entire file.\n\n";
                for (int counter = 0; counter < 45; counter++) {
                    int num = counter + 1;
                    results += num + " was a jackpot number "
                            + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
                }
            } else {
                results = "An Analsis of Bonus Numbers for the entire file.\n\n";
                for (int counter = 0; counter < 45; counter++) {
                    int num = counter + 1;
                    results += num + " was a bonus number "
                            + bonusnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
                }
            }
        }
        if (args.length == 2) {
            if (choice == 1) {
                if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
                    results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for the entire file.\n\n";
                else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
                    results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all regular draws.\n\n";
                else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
                    results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all special draws.\n\n";
                else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                    results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws.\n\n";
                else
                    results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws.\n\n";
                for (int counter = 0; counter < 45; counter++) {
                    int num = counter + 1;
                    results += num + " was a jackpot number "
                            + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
                }
            } else {
                if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
                    results = "An Analsis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for the entire file.\n\n";
                else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
                    results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all regular draws.\n\n";
                else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
                    results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all special draws.\n\n";
                else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                    results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws.\n\n";
                else
                    results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws.\n\n";
                for (int counter = 0; counter < 45; counter++) {
                    int num = counter + 1;
                    results += num + " was a bonus number "
                            + bonusnumbers[counter]
                            + "times and a jackpot number "
                            + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
                }
                if (args.length == 3) {
                    int numb = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                    if (choice == 1) {
                        if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for the entire file";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all regular draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all special draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                        else
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";
                        if (numb == 2)
                            results += "on Wednesday draws.\n\n";
                        else if (numb == 1)
                            results += " on Saturday draws.\n\n";
                        else
                            results += " for all draws.\n\n";
                        for (int counter = 0; counter < 45; counter++) {
                            int num = counter + 1;
                            results += num + " was a jackpot number "
                                    + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
                            results = "An Analsis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for the entire file";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all regular draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all special draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                        else
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";
                        if (numb == 2)
                            results += " on Wednesday draws.\n\n";
                        else if (numb == 1)
                            results += " on Saturday draws.\n\n";
                        else
                            results += " for all draws.\n\n";
                        for (int counter = 0; counter < 45; counter++) {
                            int num = counter + 1;
                            results += num + " was a bonus number "
                                    + bonusnumbers[counter]
                                    + "times and a jackpot number "
                                    + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (args.length == 5) {
                    int numb = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                    if (choice == 1) {
                        if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for the entire file";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all regular draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all special draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                        else
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";
                        if (numb == 2)
                            results += " on Wednesday draws\n\n";
                        else if (numb == 1)
                            results += " on Saturday draws\n\n";
                        else
                            results += " for all draws\n\n";
                        results += "for " + args[3] + ".\n\n";
                        for (int counter = 0; counter < 45; counter++) {
                            int num = counter + 1;
                            results += num + " was a jackpot number "
                                    + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
                            results = "An Analsis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for the entire file";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all regular draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all special draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                        else
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";
                        if (numb == 2)
                            results += " on Wednesday draws";
                        else if (numb == 1)
                            results += " on Saturday draws";
                        else
                            results += " for all draws";
                        results += "for " + args[3] + ".\n\n";
                        for (int counter = 0; counter < 45; counter++) {
                            int num = counter + 1;
                            results += num + " was a bonus number "
                                    + bonusnumbers[counter]
                                    + "times and a jackpot number "
                                    + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (args.length == 5) {
                    int numb = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                    if (choice == 1) {
                        if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for the entire file";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all regular draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all special draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                        else
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";
                        if (numb == 2)
                            results += " on Wednesday draws\n\n";
                        else if (numb == 1)
                            results += " on Saturday draws\n\n";
                        else
                            results += " for all draws\n\n";
                        results += "between " + args[3] + " and " + args[4]
                                + ".\n\n";
                        for (int counter = 0; counter < 45; counter++) {
                            int num = counter + 1;
                            results += num + " was a jackpot number "
                                    + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("A"))
                            results = "An Analsis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for the entire file";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("R"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all regular draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("S"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all special draws";
                        else if ((args[1].toUpperCase()).contentEquals("LP1"))
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 1 draws";
                        else
                            results = "An Analysis of Jackpot and Bonus Numbers for all Lotto Plus 2 draws";
                        if (numb == 2)
                            results += " on Wednesday draws";
                        else if (numb == 1)
                            results += " on Saturday draws";
                        else
                            results += " for all draws";
                        results += "between " + args[3] + " and " + args[4]
                                + ".\n\n";
                        for (int counter = 0; counter < 45; counter++) {
                            int num = counter + 1;
                            results += num + " was a bonus number "
                                    + bonusnumbers[counter]
                                    + "times and a jackpot number "
                                    + jackpotnumbers[counter] + "times.\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, results, "Analysing the Lotto", 1);
    }
}
```

Good Luck